# Electron app.makeSingleInstance to avoid multiple instances thrown javascript error

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm using electron 2.0.7 and I want to prevent multiple instances of the app by using app.makeSingleInstance.

It works but when i'm trying to run another instance of the app I get this error: "A Javascript error is occurred in the main process" as a pop up.

This is the code in main.ts:

```
function checkSingleInstance() {
  // to make singleton instance
  const isSecondInstance = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (win) {
      if (win.isMinimized()) {
        win.restore();
        win.focus();
      }
    }
  });

  if (isSecondInstance) {
    app.quit();
    return;
  }
}

checkSingleInstance();
```

This is the error:

[image: A Javascript error is occurred in the main process]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `app.quit()` with `app.exit()`.

`app.exit()` does not emit events before quitting as opposed to `app.quit()` which does the proper cleanup.

It's hard to say exactly where the error is coming from and why, but this issue is documented [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8862).

Answer (score 0):

After completing the source code you posted, I can run it using Electron 2.0.7 just fine.

The error you're seeing probably stems from some other part of your code. Judging by the error message, check if you import a module by the name `screen` somewhere.

---

Here's your source code, completed to a MCVE:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let win = null

console.log(`Node ${process.versions.node}, Chrome ${process.versions.chrome}, Electron ${process.versions.electron}`)

function checkSingleInstance() {
  // to make singleton instance
  const isSecondInstance = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
    // Someone tried to run a second instance, we should focus our window.
    if (win) {
      if (win.isMinimized()) {
        win.restore();
        win.focus();
      }
    }
  });

  if (isSecondInstance) {
    console.log("Exiting because another instance is running")
    app.quit();
    return;
  }
}

checkSingleInstance();

app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 200, height: 200});
  win.on('closed', () => win = null);
});
```

Comment: Hi, here the full code: https://github.com/ulver2812/aws-s3-backup/blob/milestone-1.5.0/main.ts
I don't posted it here because it's long. Thanks

Comment: Please make a new minimal code example that only demonstrates your issue (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This is part of the effort expected from users before posting a question.

Comment: makeSingleInstance is deprecated. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56161168/typeerror-app-makesingleinstance-is-not-a-function