# TypeError: app.makeSingleInstance is not a function

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Upgrading from Electron v2.0.3 to the latest relase v5.0.1

When I try running electron, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: app.makeSingleInstance is not a function
```

I believe this is because the api has changed. I cannot find what the equivalent for this would be. Any help would be appreciated!

main.js (was working fine in v2.0):

```
    let appInstance= null,
        mainWindow = null,

    appInstance = app.makeSingleInstance(() => {
        if (mainWindow) {
            if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) {
                mainWindow.restore();
            }
            mainWindow.focus();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the API has changed since Electron 4.0: [Planned Breaking API Changes (4.0)](https://electronjs.org/docs/all#planned-breaking-api-changes-40):

> app.makeSingleInstance
>
> ```
> // Deprecated
> app.makeSingleInstance((argv, cwd) => {
>   /* ... */
> })
> // Replace with
> app.requestSingleInstanceLock()
> app.on('second-instance', (event, argv, cwd) => {
>   /* ... */
> })
> ```

More details are available in the documentation for the [requestSingleInstanceLock()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#apprequestsingleinstancelock) method and the ['second-instance'](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-second-instance) event.